# $_ENV vs $_SERVER vs $_GLOBAL

Tags: php

В чем разница между использованием в первую очередь $_ENV vs $SERVER ?

Знаю причину что $_ENV по умолчанию отключено и включить его нужно через php.ini. 
Или может $_ENV служит больше для своих переменных а $_SERVER для доступа к переменных настройки сервера ?

По умолчанию $_ENV содержит весь одинаковый набор свойств что и $_SERVER ? 
Если я правильно предположил что $_ENV служит больше для своих переменных то почему же не использовать тогда массив $_GLOBAL?

Comment: Читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.php

Comment: Толковый ответ .. Ты не с форума javascript.ru или htmlbook пришел? Там такие умники рождаются . Где место  на хоть один ответ с моих вопросов ?

Comment: не надо мне тыкать. А в руководстве подробно расписано, что в каких массивах хранится.

Answer (score 3):

Такой переменной как `$_GLOBAL` не существует в принципе.
Есть переменная, которая называется `$GLOBALS`, но в ней нет ничего такого, чего не было бы в `$_ENV` или `$_SERVER`, и вообще пользоваться ей крайне нежелательно.

Поэтому речь может идти только о последних двух.
Правильнее, наверное, пользоваться `$_SERVER`, поскольку, во-первых, она всегда доступна, а во-вторых, может содержать переменные, отсутствующие в `$_ENV` - например, начинающиеся на `PHP_` и некоторые другие.

`$_SERVER` - внутренняя переменная РНР, которой управляет он сам. А `$_ENV` - это всего лишь отражение списка переменных окружения в системе.